# Combining multithreaded C++ and Unity

Tags: c++, multithreading, unity-game-engine

It says that Unity is not thread-safe. What does this exactly imply? If I have a multithreaded C++ DLL that I want to import and use in Unity, is there a procedure to make it compatible?

Comment: What is "it"? And what issue do you have with your DLL?

Comment: Unity components can utilize multithreaded code, but only the main thread can call the Unity API.

Comment: I write multi-threaded stuff in Unity all the time... so care to give us a reference of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no problem, actually the single-thread limitation is typical for almost all user interface implementations. There are multiple ways how you can solve your problem. I don't know which solution is the best for Unity, I am just providing this as an example how you can proceed: You can for example have a single UI thread and call all Unity-related stuff only from this single thread. Use all other threads for whatever you want and let them communicate with your UI thread. The UI thread is then also de-facto mediator between Unity and the rest of your application.

Comment: Re, "single-thread limitation is typical..." I've lost the link, but one of the designers of AWT and Swing wrote about how GUI systems typically have a deep heirarchy of components in which business-logic typically goes from the root toward the leaves, while event handling goes in the opposite direction. He said that the opposite-direction-ness makes it _very_ hard to design a multi-threaded system that is free from deadlocks. They tried with AWT, and Swing happened after they realized that it was never going to work well.